# How to make images within a wrapper span the full width of the wrapper

Tags: html, css, image, width, centering

I was wondering how I could make images in my website span the full width of my wrapper section of my website. Bare in mind this wrapper is 85% of the entire body of the site.

Here is the HTML for the images in question:

```
<div id="index_banner">
                                         <img class="bottom" src="images/SPAWN IMAGE.png" alt="INDEX BANNER">
                                         <img class="top" src="images/SURVIVAL IMAGE - GAMEMODES.png" alt="INDEX BANNER 2">
                                     </div>
```

Here is the CSS for the images on that page:

```
#index_banner {height: 360px;
               position: relative;}

#index_banner img {position: absolute;
                   animation: cf4FadeInOut 15s;
                   -webkit-animation: cf4FadeInOut 15s;
                   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}

#index_banner img:nth-child(odd) {-webkit-animation-delay: -8s;
                                  animation-delay: 8s;
                                  animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;}

@-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
   0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0; 
    }
    40%{
        opacity:1; 
    }
    75%{
        opacity:1; 
    }
    85%{
        opacity:1; 
    }

    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }

}

@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {

   0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0; 
    }
    40%{
        opacity:1; 
    }
    75%{
        opacity:1; 
    }
    85%{
        opacity:1; 
    }

    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8f0fu3g/ (with the 85% width).

Comment: Is there a reason, why you aren't just adding 100% width to the <img>?

Comment: I added that now and it works, didn't think to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o73ceL3q/) does what you're looking for:

```
#index_banner {height: 360px;
               position: relative;
               width: 85%;}                 <-- added this

#index_banner img {position: absolute;
                   width: 100%;             <-- and this
                   animation: cf4FadeInOut 15s;
                   -webkit-animation:
.................
.................
```

With this, the `index banner` takes up 85% of the page width, and the images inside take up 100% of the `index banner` width.

Comment: Nope, that just doers this: http://gyazo.com/1a32b0be3e7b83763c345b0bf5804af2 I want it so this: http://gyazo.com/a1de40efaf2127ee3d58b4af8dc6d3da image has the same width of the wrapper that's 85% of the entire width of the page

Comment: You were nearly right, the 100% width gave me a clue, so you were partly right XD.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I figured it out:

Adding this to the images in the HTML:

```
height="360"
```

And adding this to the CSS IMG div:

```
width:100%;
```

Adding this produces the desired result [of](http://gyazo.com/0e2cb3b25be96a7e4efcfa0fdefeacc7):